# High Sierra occasionally shows a white/grey screen and I have to switch off and restart

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash

The picture attached shows what I see when my computer "crashes".
It happens occasionally. It may be because of heavy load. Or because
I have it open many hours. I don't really know.

Has anyone else experienced this? Can you help? How can I trouble shoot?

Note that I have Mac Book Pro

MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
2,5 GHz Intel Core i7
16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
AMD Radeon R9 M370X 2048 MB
Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

Note: the star shaped light area in the middle is my camera flash light. Please, ignore.

[image: Grey screen]

Comment: The light area in the middle is the flash light of my camera. Please, ignore.

Answer (score 1):

I would ssh into the box and run **sysdiagnose** and **top** to see what’s happening.

If SSH won’t let you spawn a new process then you have a key piece of information and can press the key card to get a cyst diagnose and then look at the system logs want to to force the system down by holding the power button.